# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 17710: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, web-scraping

I'm trying to print a string from an [archived web crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/), but when I do I get this error:

```
print page['html']
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 17710: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try print `unicode(page['html'])` I get:

```
print unicode(page['html'],errors='ignore')
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

Any idea how I can properly code this string, or at least get it to print?  Thanks.

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: This is by far the most common python question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to *encode* the unicode you saved to display it, not *decode* it -- unicode is the unencoded form. You should always specify an encoding, so that your code will be portable. The "usual" pick is `utf-8`:

```
print page['html'].encode('utf-8')
```

If you don't specify an encoding, whether or not it works will depend on what you're `print`ing to -- your editor, OS, terminal program, etc.