# Error using Tweepy to update Twitter in another language other than English.

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I am having problems using Tweepy with characters different than ASCII. I tried a number of different approaches but each of them I have a different Error in the terminal.

So, first I do all the dance that Twitter asks and import what I need:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from random import randint
import tweepy, sys, time
import requests
import unicodedata

consumer_key="x"
consumer_secret="y"
access_token="z"
access_token_secret="w"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Then, I go to a website to find sentences to Tweet.

```
page = requests.get("www.webpage.com")
poemT = html.fromstring(page.text) 
phrases = poemT.xpath('//div[@class="mainData"]/text()')
```

When trying to convert a sentence I can't find a format that suits the function api.update_satus() and I have the following error messages for each different try.

**Try 1:**

```
tuite = phrases.pop(0)
api.update_status(tuite)
```

**Error:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

With this error I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322432/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xe7-in-position-177), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264892/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u201c-in-position-3), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20?lq=1) and a few others suggesting the solution bellow. However, I have no problems when trying to print the sentences. I imagine that is why it did not solve my problem.

**Try 2**

```
tuite = phrases.pop(0).encode('utf-8')
api.update_status(tuite)
```

**Error:**

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Headers indicate a formencoded body but body was not decodable.
```

With this error I could not find anything related. But I tried just to transform the sentence in ASCII as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols/1207479#1207479) question says. But I still got an error.

**Try 3**

```
title = phrases.pop(0)
tuite = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii','ignore')
api.update_status(tuite)
```

**Error:**

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'media_ids parameter is invalid.', u'code': 44}]
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851585/tweepy-update-status-with-media-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode) question, but it was related to updating with media.

**Finally**

I found [this](https://github.com/dialelo/turses/issues/202) discution on git suggesting that my problem is a bug(?) to be fixed in Tweepy.

Any thoughts? I would be happy if I could convert the text in a format that api.update_status() accepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer in this link:

[Traceback when updating status on twitter via Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527352/traceback-when-updating-status-on-twitter-via-tweepy)

Turns out I am supposed to call the update function like follows:

```
 api.update_status(status=tuite)
```